# How to make JMeter's BinaryTCPClientImpl accept ACK?

Tags: tcp, jmeter, tcpclient

I use JMeter's BinaryTCPClientImpl to send a command of a custom protocol. By design this command doesn't produce a response from the application that receives it such that the only response which comes back to JMeter is the TCP ACK frame. JMeter's TCP Sampler doesn't see ACK as a response and thus a read timeout occurs follwed by a closure of the socket. According to the documentation I have tried to set the end-of-line byte value to greater than 128 to turn off the check of the end of stream but nothing has changed with respect to the read timeout.

Is there a way to make BinaryTCPClientImpl accept TCP ACK as a valid response without implementing a custom sampler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the ACK packet is a part of *sending* stage for tcp communication. So if you have sent your request successfully, then your requirement was met.

By default, BinaryTCPClientImpl has no such ability to not wait for the response. So you will have to implement your own BinaryTCPClientImplNoResp class, deriving from BinaryTCPClientImpl and overriding its read() method. For now I know no better way to achieve your goal.